# Redirect All External Links

Tags: php, redirect

I want redirect all external links, 
for example when you link a external website like google.com, it will be link like this "redirector.php?url=google.com" then goes to google.com

also, i want to that link redirected after 30 secs.
that means, after you click the link (redirector.php?url=google.com) it go to redirector.php with a countdown (30 secs) then after 30 secs it goes to google.com.

i see something like this on a vBulletin forum, but my site isn't vBulletin.

mysite.com/redirector.php?url=google.com

but i want it won't affect on my insider links

mysite.com/news.php

is there anyway to do this via php?

Thanks in advance

Here is my work:
 'url',
                'type' => 'unparsed_equals',
                'before' => '',
                'after' => '',
                'validate' => create_function('&$tag, &$data, $disabled', '
                    if (strpos($data, \'http://mysite.com/redirector.php?url=\') !== 0 && strpos($data, \'https://mysite.com/redirector.php?url=\') !== 0)
                        $data = \'http://mysite.com/redirector.php?url=\' . $data;
                '),
?>
but i need to replace something instead http://mysite.com , that could realize the url, something like $siteurl

any idea?

Comment: Anything wrong with the [546,000 available results](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=countdown+redirect&oq=countdown+redirect&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.410.4091.0.4342.24.14.3.7.8.1.267.1662.7j6j1.14.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.0EICi_b_jIg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44990110,d.bGE&fp=4949c79d3b14c8f6&biw=1235&bih=683) in a google search with your search term?

Comment: Yes there is some ways to do this in php, what have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for the timeout like this:

redirector.php

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
    setTimeout("location.href = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']); ?>';", 30000);
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**redirector.php**

**Method 1**

```
<?php
$url=$_GET["url"];
sleep(30);
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

**Method 2**

```
<?php
$url=$_GET["url"];
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"30;URL=$url\" />";
?>
```